# Update simulation results into a live-dash-graph

Tags: python, simulation, plotly-dash

I've done a simulation and while the code is running I want to show a live-updating-graph.
In this case I want to show the **cost** in every **week**.
X= date, y= cost.
The last part of simulation code is something like:

```
def simulation(path, df, orders, stores, this_week, last_week):
while this_week < last_week:

    cost = items_move(orders, stores, this_week, path)

    ###I want the graph takes cost####

    ordering(df, this_week, path)

    this_week = this_week + timedelta(weeks=1)
```

For the graph I found this example:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash import dcc # dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque

X = deque(maxlen=20)
X.append(1)
Y = deque(maxlen=20)
Y.append(1)
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1000,
            n_intervals = 0
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
        [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])

def update_graph_scatter(n):
    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1]*random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))
data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=list(X),
        y=list(Y),
        name='Scatter',
        mode= 'lines+markers'
        )

return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                            yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=5000)
```

I've tried something like this but While doesn't work anymore after the callback

```
def simulation(path, df, orders, stores, this_week, last_week):

    X = deque()
    X.append(this_week - timedelta(weeks=1))
    Y = deque()
    Y.append(0)

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
            dcc.Interval(
                id='graph-update',
                interval=1000,
                n_intervals = 0
            ),])

    while this_week < last_week:

        cost = items_move(orders, stores, this_week, path)

        #X.append(this_week)        
        #Y.append(cost)

        @app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
                [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])

        def update_graph_scatter(n):
            X.append(X[-1] + timedelta(weeks=1))
            Y.append(cost)

            data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
                    x=list(X),
                    y=list(Y),
                    name='Scatter',
                    mode= 'lines+markers'
                    )

            return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                                        yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}
     
        ordering(df, this_week, path)
        this_week = this_week + timedelta(weeks=1)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run_server(port=5000)
```

Any idea?Thanks